# Timer giving error on meeting conditions

Tags: java, swing, timertask

Alright guys, i got a new problem, i made a timer that checks if a button meets certain requeriments each second, and im aware that this isn't the best method but i wont use this program for long so i just want it to work.

The problem i'm having is the timer gives me the following error :

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at proyecto.Diseños$RemindTask.run(Diseños.java:3561)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Line 3561 is :

```
if(Boton61.getBackground() == Color.red && Boton51.getBackground() == Color.red && Boton41.getBackground() == Color.red && Boton31.getBackground() == Color.red 
                && colores.colorjugador[0] == 1) System.out.println("El jugador ha ganado !");
```

The full code is :

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package proyecto;


import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import static proyecto.Proyecto.turnosjugador1;
import static proyecto.Proyecto.turnosjugador2;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;




/**
 *
 * @author Cristian
 *
 * */






public class Diseños extends JComponent implements ActionListener {

   JButton Boton1, Boton2, Boton3, Boton4, Boton5, Boton6, Boton7;

   JButton Boton11,Boton21,Boton31,Boton41,Boton51,Boton61;
   JButton Boton12,Boton22,Boton32,Boton42,Boton52,Boton62;
   JButton Boton13,Boton23,Boton33,Boton43,Boton53,Boton63;
   JButton Boton14,Boton24,Boton34,Boton44,Boton54,Boton64;
   JButton Boton15,Boton25,Boton35,Boton45,Boton55,Boton65;
   JButton Boton16,Boton26,Boton36,Boton46,Boton56,Boton66;
   JButton Boton17,Boton27,Boton37,Boton47,Boton57,Boton67;




  public Diseños()
  {

        Timer timer;
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), 0, //initial delay
        1 * 1000);

   Boton1=new JButton("lol"); 
    Boton1.setBounds(90, 410, 30, 30); 
    Boton1.setBackground(Color.black);
    Component agregar1 = add(Boton1);
    Boton1.addActionListener(this);

    Boton2=new JButton("lol"); 
    Boton2.setBounds(150, 410, 30, 30); 
    Boton2.setBackground(Color.black);
    Component agregar2 = add(Boton2);
    Boton2.addActionListener(this);

    Boton3=new JButton("lol"); 
    Boton3.setBounds(210, 410, 30, 30); 
    Boton3.setBackground(Color.black);
    Component agregar3 = add(Boton3);
    Boton3.addActionListener(this);

    Boton4=new JButton("lol"); 
    Boton4.setBounds(270, 410, 30, 30); 
    Boton4.setBackground(Color.black);
    Component agregar4 = add(Boton4);
    Boton4.addActionListener(this);

    Boton5=new JButton("lol"); 
    Boton5.setBounds(330, 410, 30, 30); 
    Boton5.setBackground(Color.black);
    Component agregar5 = add(Boton5);
    Boton5.addActionListener(this);

    Boton6=new JButton("lol"); 
    Boton6.setBounds(390, 410, 30, 30); 
    Boton6.setBackground(Color.black);
    Component agregar6 = add(Boton6);
    Boton6.addActionListener(this);

    Boton7=new JButton("lol"); 
    Boton7.setBounds(450, 410, 30, 30); 
    Boton7.setBackground(Color.black);
    Component agregar7 = add(Boton7);
    Boton7.addActionListener(this);


    Boton11=new JButton(""); 
    Boton11.setBounds(85, 10, 40, 60); 
    Boton11.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar11 = add(Boton11);
    Boton11.addActionListener(this);

    Boton21=new JButton(""); 
    Boton21.setBounds(85, 70, 40, 60); 
    Boton21.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar21 = add(Boton21);
    Boton21.addActionListener(this);

    Boton31=new JButton(""); 
    Boton31.setBounds(85, 130, 40, 60); 
    Boton31.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar31 = add(Boton31);
    Boton31.addActionListener(this);

    Boton41=new JButton(""); 
    Boton41.setBounds(85, 190, 40, 60); 
    Boton41.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar41 = add(Boton41);
    Boton41.addActionListener(this);

    Boton51=new JButton(""); 
    Boton51.setBounds(85, 250, 40, 60); 
    Boton51.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar51 = add(Boton51);
    Boton51.addActionListener(this);

    Boton61=new JButton(""); 
    Boton61.setBounds(85, 310, 40, 60); 
    Boton61.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar61 = add(Boton61);
    Boton61.addActionListener(this);


    Boton12=new JButton(""); 
    Boton12.setBounds(145, 10, 40, 60); 
    Boton12.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar12 = add(Boton12);
    Boton12.addActionListener(this);

    Boton22=new JButton(""); 
    Boton22.setBounds(145, 70, 40, 60); 
    Boton22.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar22 = add(Boton22);
    Boton22.addActionListener(this);

    Boton32=new JButton(""); 
    Boton32.setBounds(145, 130, 40, 60); 
    Boton32.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar32 = add(Boton32);
    Boton32.addActionListener(this);

    Boton42=new JButton(""); 
    Boton42.setBounds(145, 190, 40, 60); 
    Boton42.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar42 = add(Boton42);
    Boton42.addActionListener(this);

    Boton52=new JButton(""); 
    Boton52.setBounds(145, 250, 40, 60); 
    Boton52.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar52 = add(Boton52);
    Boton52.addActionListener(this);

    Boton62=new JButton(""); 
    Boton62.setBounds(145, 310, 40, 60); 
    Boton62.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar62 = add(Boton62);
    Boton62.addActionListener(this);

    Boton13=new JButton(""); 
    Boton13.setBounds(205, 10, 40, 60); 
    Boton13.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar13 = add(Boton13);
    Boton13.addActionListener(this);

    Boton23=new JButton(""); 
    Boton23.setBounds(205, 70, 40, 60); 
    Boton23.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar23 = add(Boton23);
    Boton23.addActionListener(this);

    Boton33=new JButton(""); 
    Boton33.setBounds(205, 130, 40, 60); 
    Boton33.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar33 = add(Boton33);
    Boton33.addActionListener(this);

    Boton43=new JButton(""); 
    Boton43.setBounds(205, 190, 40, 60); 
    Boton43.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar43 = add(Boton43);
    Boton43.addActionListener(this);

    Boton53=new JButton(""); 
    Boton53.setBounds(205, 250, 40, 60); 
    Boton53.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar53 = add(Boton53);
    Boton53.addActionListener(this);

    Boton63=new JButton(""); 
    Boton63.setBounds(205, 310, 40, 60); 
    Boton63.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar63 = add(Boton63);
    Boton63.addActionListener(this);

    Boton14=new JButton(""); 
    Boton14.setBounds(265, 10, 40, 60); 
    Boton14.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar14 = add(Boton14);
    Boton14.addActionListener(this);

    Boton24=new JButton(""); 
    Boton24.setBounds(265, 70, 40, 60); 
    Boton24.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar24 = add(Boton24);
    Boton24.addActionListener(this);

    Boton34=new JButton(""); 
    Boton34.setBounds(265, 130, 40, 60); 
    Boton34.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar34 = add(Boton34);
    Boton34.addActionListener(this);

    Boton44=new JButton(""); 
    Boton44.setBounds(265, 190, 40, 60); 
    Boton44.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar44 = add(Boton44);
    Boton44.addActionListener(this);

    Boton54=new JButton(""); 
    Boton54.setBounds(265, 250, 40, 60); 
    Boton54.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar54 = add(Boton54);
    Boton54.addActionListener(this);

    Boton64=new JButton(""); 
    Boton64.setBounds(265, 310, 40, 60); 
    Boton64.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar64 = add(Boton64);
    Boton64.addActionListener(this);

    Boton15=new JButton(""); 
    Boton15.setBounds(325, 10, 40, 60); 
    Boton15.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar15 = add(Boton15);
    Boton15.addActionListener(this);

    Boton25=new JButton(""); 
    Boton25.setBounds(325, 70, 40, 60); 
    Boton25.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar25 = add(Boton25);
    Boton25.addActionListener(this);

    Boton35=new JButton(""); 
    Boton35.setBounds(325, 130, 40, 60); 
    Boton35.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar35 = add(Boton35);
    Boton35.addActionListener(this);

    Boton45=new JButton(""); 
    Boton45.setBounds(325, 190, 40, 60); 
    Boton45.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar45 = add(Boton45);
    Boton45.addActionListener(this);

    Boton55=new JButton(""); 
    Boton55.setBounds(325, 250, 40, 60); 
    Boton55.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar55 = add(Boton55);
    Boton55.addActionListener(this);

    Boton65=new JButton(""); 
    Boton65.setBounds(325, 310, 40, 60); 
    Boton65.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar65 = add(Boton65);
    Boton65.addActionListener(this);

    Boton16=new JButton(""); 
    Boton16.setBounds(385, 10, 40, 60); 
    Boton16.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar16 = add(Boton16);
    Boton16.addActionListener(this);

    Boton26=new JButton(""); 
    Boton26.setBounds(385, 70, 40, 60); 
    Boton26.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar26 = add(Boton26);
    Boton26.addActionListener(this);

    Boton36=new JButton(""); 
    Boton36.setBounds(385, 130, 40, 60); 
    Boton36.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar36 = add(Boton36);
    Boton36.addActionListener(this);

    Boton46=new JButton(""); 
    Boton46.setBounds(385, 190, 40, 60); 
    Boton46.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar46 = add(Boton46);
    Boton46.addActionListener(this);

    Boton56=new JButton(""); 
    Boton56.setBounds(385, 250, 40, 60); 
    Boton56.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar56 = add(Boton56);
    Boton56.addActionListener(this);

    Boton66=new JButton(""); 
    Boton66.setBounds(385, 310, 40, 60); 
    Boton66.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar66 = add(Boton66);
    Boton66.addActionListener(this);

    Boton17=new JButton(""); 
    Boton17.setBounds(445, 10, 40, 60); 
    Boton17.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar17 = add(Boton17);
    Boton17.addActionListener(this);

    Boton27=new JButton(""); 
    Boton27.setBounds(445, 70, 40, 60); 
    Boton27.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar27 = add(Boton27);
    Boton27.addActionListener(this);

    Boton37=new JButton(""); 
    Boton37.setBounds(445, 130, 40, 60); 
    Boton37.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar37 = add(Boton37);
    Boton37.addActionListener(this);

    Boton47=new JButton(""); 
    Boton47.setBounds(445, 190, 40, 60); 
    Boton47.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar47 = add(Boton47);
    Boton47.addActionListener(this);

    Boton57=new JButton(""); 
    Boton57.setBounds(445, 250, 40, 60); 
    Boton57.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar57 = add(Boton57);
    Boton57.addActionListener(this);

    Boton67=new JButton(""); 
    Boton67.setBounds(445, 310, 40, 60); 
    Boton67.setBackground(Color.white);
    Component agregar67 = add(Boton67);
    Boton67.addActionListener(this);   



  }

   @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {    



    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawRect (570, 10, 300, 200);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(570, 10, 300, 200);
    g.drawRect (570, 250, 300, 200);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(570, 250, 300, 200);
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    Font oldFont=getFont();
    Font fuente=new Font("Primer Jugador", Font.BOLD, 14);
    g.setFont(fuente);
    g.drawString("Primer Jugador", 580, 30);
    Font titulo=new Font("Segundo Jugador", Font.BOLD, 14);
    g.setFont(titulo);
    g.drawString("Segundo Jugador", 580, 270);
    g.drawString("[ " + Proyecto.primernombre + " ]", 580, 50);
    g.drawString("[ " + Proyecto.segundonombre + " ]", 580, 290);
    g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    g.fillRoundRect(10, 5, 550, 450, 50, 50);
    g.drawString("Turno Numero : " + turnosjugador1, 580, 70);
    g.drawString("Turno Numero : " + turnosjugador2, 580, 310);


  }











    }


class RemindTask extends TimerTask {


    @Override
    public void run() {

        if(Boton61.getBackground() == Color.red && Boton51.getBackground() == Color.red && Boton41.getBackground() == Color.red && Boton31.getBackground() == Color.red 
                && colores.colorjugador[0] == 1) System.out.println("El jugador ha ganado !");

        //timer.cancel(); //Not necessary because we call System.exit    




    }
  }



}
```

I am aware that alot of lines are a waste of unnecessary space and the program could be done way shorter with loops, but i need to make it as simple as possible so other students understand it.

I just want to know why the timer is giving me such an error when using that IF on the timer, any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you need to interact with the UI via some kind of timer, you should use a `javax.swing.Timer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that the timer has executed while the class is been initialized...If you take a look at the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)), the `delay` parameter is

> delay - delay in milliseconds **before** task is to be executed.

This means it is likely been executed almost immediately, meaning that some of the instance fields you are relying on haven't been initialised yet.

When dealing with the Swing UI, it's generally better to use a `javax.swing.Timer`, as it calls it's `ActionListener` within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, reducing the risk of race conditions like you have.

It would also be better to simply attach an `ActionListener` to the buttons and check the state as they are clicked, but that's just my opinion

Comment: Nevermind, you're great, i just added 3 seconds to the delay and things work great, thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: Why can't you check to see if, at the completion of the current move, you have a winning condition?